# Can we use just the controller name and id parameter in URL for Asp.net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-routing

Suppose, I have a controller named *category* with an action method, *Index* which takes *id* as parameter.

Therefore, the URL appears like this : *category/Index/foo*. As you can see, the Index segment just doesn't seem right. A URL such as this : *category/foo* will be more readable and understandable.

Just like in SO, these guys use : *question/857344*

How can I achieve such a URL. In my routes, I have set defaults for all three : controller, action and id. But, when i try to visit *category/foo*, I get the "404 - resource not find"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
               "Category/{id}",
               new { controller = "Category", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
               );
```

You map it how you want it to look then specify the Action.

Also make sure you put it before the default route

Comment: How will I use Html.ActionLink in this case ? Currently When I use `@Html.ActionLink("Category", new { id = "22", title = "something" })` , it is converted to `<a href = "Home/Category/22?title=something`. With this route, Do i need to directly use anchor tag instead of Html.ActionLink ??

Comment: I think you need you need to specify the controller and the action in your new { }.  also after the {} try , null for the last param

Comment: I am not able to get it working....I tried `Html.ActionLink("Trial", null, "Category", new { id = model.Id, title = "something" })`

Comment: No Sorry, your action link should be like

@Html.ActionLink("Trial", "Index", "Category", new { id = 1 },null) for example
the null is at the end.  It will know to route you to /category/id because of the route in the global